# Navigable clojure stacktraces with emacs, nREPL, and clojure.test

Tags: testing, emacs, clojure, nrepl

I'm using emacs with nREPL via cider, and I've got a suite of clojure.test-based tests that I run to see when I've broken things (which is a lot as I'm fairly new to clojure.) I've tried two methods to run these tests - first by invoked the external "lein test" command and second by using clojure-test - and both work but neither gives completely satisfactory results. What I want is to be able to "navigate" the results of the tests, i.e. click on failures and stacktraces to go to the sources of failure.

I've poked around a bit with clojure-stacktrace-mode, but, while fairly impressive, that only seems to apply to stacktraces generated in the nREPL buffer.

So my question is: is there a way to get the behavior I want? Or maybe another way to get equivalent functionality? I feel like all the parts are there, but that I'm putting them together incorrectly.

Comment: Btw, clojure-test-mode is scheduled for [termination](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode/issues/214)... Once running the tests gets properly integrated with cider (via middleware), we'll get the behaviour you're looking for.

Comment: OK, that's good to know. The emacs/clojure situation for those of us not doing the development is a bit confusing right now. Any ETA on the cider updates?

Comment: None at the moment. Best case scenario - in a couple of months or so. There are a lot of (more important) features in the cider pipeline already. Of course - if someone volunteers to work on this it may happen earlier.